# How to trigger build on upstream project on event in downstream project Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am using jenkins [multijob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) to build my projects and deploy builds. Currently the structure is below

```
Multi Job Project 
  Build Phase  
    Project A
    **Project B**
    Project C
  Deploy Phase
    Project D
```

Each project is configured with git SCM & when I build Multijob project, It builds correctly.

I want to trigger Multijob project build on `github push event` on project B.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 1:**

Basically you need to add **Project B** repository as a submodule in your **Project A** repository.

More info : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

A handy command to do this : `git submodule add git://github.com/username/project.git`

> More info on this matter here :
> [how to trigger build in jenkins when changes committed to submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721392/how-to-trigger-build-in-jenkins-when-changes-committed-to-submodule)
>
> Also :
> [How to configure Git post commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794568/how-to-configure-git-post-commit-hook)

**Main  Answer:**

Basically you have to configure "Webhooks and Services" in the github repository of Project B.

[image: "Webhooks and Services Configuration snapshot"]

1. This tutorial might help you: (specifically the portion of the tutorial where github project is configured)

   https://learning-continuous-deployment.github.io/jenkins/github/2015/04/17/github-jenkins/
2. This stackoverflow answer is also helpful:

   [Jenkins-Build when a change is pushed to GitHub option is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576881/jenkins-build-when-a-change-is-pushed-to-github-option-is-not-working)
3. This four kitchens tutorial covers Jenkins and Github private repo integration and push event triggers.

   http://fourkitchens.com/blog/article/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github

Comment: I have already configured these. The main thing is to trigger build on main project whenever there is a change in sub project.

Comment: Shahab, no project is nested inside any project. Multijob project is parallel to jenkins freestyle project, in which you create a project having multiple phases.